# Unanswered Questions without Upvotes

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I've already noticed [Encourage upvotes on unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20780/encourage-upvotes-on-unanswered-questions) but I want to know is anything done about the huge amount of old questions classified unanswered?

Does stack overflow send out any messages to the authors along the lines of " Your question is x months old, you have y answers, please pick an answer if it helped you or add your own solution if it was none of the answers provided"?

If it doesn't already (I haven't got any questions old enough to know), Then could it be implemented? ***Is there somewhere I could vote for such a feature?***

I'd like to help improve the quality of results by answering some of the neglected questions, but it's hard to find relevant ones in the massive backlog

Comment: There isn't a requirement here for the authors to accept anything (although it's a nice thing when they do, both to let people know they found a solution and to say thanks to the answerer). Therefore, reminding them to accept one wouldn't quite be proper. We get many questions from people who stop by with a problem, post a question, get an answer (or find one themselves) and never come back.

Comment: Indeed, I think my real question is "is there a way for me to see questions which really are likely to still need an answer". It jsut seemed to me that a fair solution might be to prompt authors to try and add their own answer if they did ever manage to fix it and thats why they havent been back to the question

Comment: If they're one time users (who may or may not have registered at SO), or just dropped by and then never came back, how exactly would you propose to "prompt" them?

Comment: I wasnt aware that people can ask things without registration. I would think any method whether oauth, google, facebook etc provides some way to send them a one-off message

Comment: Any of the registration services would have to notify you by email, and I certainly didn't give them permission to use it for anything other than my login/account. But there are tons and tons of messages from unregistered users here (see any that have plain 'userXXXXX' accounts with an unclickable name and grey silhouette avatar, with 1 reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet if you want to work on questions that needs answers is to click on the `Unanswered Questions` button and then the `My Tags` tab.  You'll never be bored again.

Comment: I've been doing just that, but often I find that there actually *is* an answer in the comments, sometimes even one that's followed by a "Thanks, that was it!" response from the OP, wasting the time of those who might otherwise be answering truly unanswered questions.  When I encounter such questions, should I go ahead and just answer them if I can?  Or is that considered bad etiquette?

Comment: You can just create an answer out of the comment.  Just reference that you got the content from the comment.